# What are "shortcodes" in All in One SEO for WordPress?

Tags: seo, wordpress

In All in One SEO > Social Meta, do we need to check the following:

1. Run shortcodes in title
2. Run shortcodes in description

What is the significance of these two settings?

[image]

Comment: Please use only one [account](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/67566/regi) to ask questions and make edits with.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress shortcodes are codes that look like eg. `[gallery]`, and are used to quickly call built-in, or plugin, functionality from within your post.

Usually, these will not work in places other than the main post content - by default, a shortcode entered into the page title, or a category description, or a social plugin's title and description in this case, would just render as the code itself - '[gallery]' - rather than whatever it was meant to render instead - a full featured image gallery.

There may be other shortcodes that are available to you depending on what plugins you have installed.

This plugin is simply giving you the option to have shortcodes work in, what I assume from the screenshot you provided is, the title and description of each social network the plugin handles.